# Non-linear boundary value problems and the fundamental matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm reading Ascher and Petzold's *Computer Methods for Ordinary Differential Equations and Differential-Algebraic Equations*, [pages 175-176](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18zNwswdy-bQq95SI7aYO8zNRErN86qkA/view?usp=sharing), problem 4. Here they introduce a more sophisticated notion of the fundamental matrix.

[image]

**Question 1:** Why does $Y$ solve that differential equation? If $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}, t) = \begin{bmatrix}y_2 \\ e^{y_1 + 1}\end{bmatrix}$, say, then $\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{y}} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ e^{y_1 + 1} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and then we're talking about $A(t)\mathbf{y}$ being $\begin{bmatrix} y_2 \\ e^{y_1 + 1}y_1 \end{bmatrix}$, and I don't see the relevance of that.

**Question 2:** If $\mathbf{f}$ is not linear, why do we care about this fundamental matrix? We can no longer add two solutions and get a third solution, right? So why would we care about this matrix that stores the solutions with initial conditions $\mathbf{e}_i$?

**Question 3:** They later go on to apply this to boundary value problems, where our boundary conditions are given as $M_1\mathbf{y}(0) + M_2 \mathbf{y}(b) = \mathbf{d}$, where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are constant matrices. They claim that when we differentiate the function $M_1\mathbf{y}(0,\mathbf{c}) + M_2\mathbf{y}(b, \mathbf{c})$ with respect to $\mathbf{c}$, they get

$$M_1 + M_2 Y(b)$$

In other words, they're saying that $\frac{\partial \mathbf{y}}{\partial \mathbf{c}}(t, \mathbf{c})\mid_{t = b}$ is $Y(b)$. I don't see why.

Comment: Regarding the last line: is'nt this true by the very definition of $Y$?

Comment: You’ve gotten question 1 backwards. $A$ isn’t the solution to the equation; $Y$ is.

Comment: @amd Thanks. I think I just wrote $A$ where I meant $Y$. Now I think it's the question I want to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y$ is the partial derivative for the constant parameters $c$. In the cited formulations these parameters can only influence the initial conditions, $y_0=y_0(c)$. $Y$ then describes how infinitesimal changes in $c$ change the solution, $y(t;c+Δc)=y(t;c)+Y(t;c)Δc+O(Δc^2)$.

For instance, you could use the initial values themselves as parameters, then $Y$ would be the Jacobi matrix that can be used to solve boundary value problems.

Or if you want to fit a class of differential equations to a given data set, then you can use $Y$ at the sample points to compute the gradient of the error function.

In the second case, you need the more general formulation for $y'(t;c)=f(t,y(t;c);c)$ where
$$
\frac{∂}{∂t}\frac{∂y}{∂c}=\frac{∂}{∂c}(f(t,y(t;c);c))=\frac{∂f}{∂y}\frac{∂y}{∂c}+\frac{∂f}{∂c}
$$
so that by assigning variables
$$
\frac{d}{dt}Y=Ay+b\text{ where }
\left\{\begin{aligned}Y&=\frac{∂y}{∂c}\\A&=\frac{∂f}{∂y}\\b&=\frac{∂f}{∂c}\end{aligned}\right.
$$